# Django, can't save ManyToMany field from admin interface using save() method

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying to save/create a ManyToMany relation while saving my model. This is my code:

```
class Invoice(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    product_ids = models.CharField(max_length=128, default='')
    products = models.ManyToManyField(Product, null=True, blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Invoice, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.product_ids:
            ids = self.product_ids.split(',')
            for id in ids:
               product = Product.objects.get(id=id)
               self.products.add(product)
            super(AllAroundCompetition, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

It is self explanatory. Sometimes I would like to create the invoice manually and I don't want to browse the whole list while pressing "ctrl" in order to select many products. So I have added a dumb extra field to pass ids in a comma separated manner (eg 25,27,90,20). This is `product_ids` field. I overrode the `save()` method to create these M2M relations. But it doesn't work. Invoice is created, but the relations are not.

What am I doing wrong?

(using django 1.5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `super(AllAroundCompetition, self).save(…)` at the bottom of your method. Adding an object to an m2m relation shouldn't need a `save` call afterwards at all, and calling `save` of another class might mess things up.

I suggest an alternative solution at all: try [using a `filter_horizontal`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.filter_horizontal) for your `products` field in the admin. It has a nicer user interface, including search. No more ctrl-holding neccessary:

```
class InvoiceAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    filter_horizontal = ('products',)
```

Answer (score 1):

M2M relation changes are saved in separate table in database.
Therefore save method saves only model itself, relation is saved after changes to model has been made in proper table in database, e.g. when creating new model it has to be created in database (save method) to add M2M foreign keys.

TL;DR:
Try overriding method ModelAdmin.save_related(self, request, form, formsets, change)
(you may have to create model admin class for this model and registering it)